# NextJS Crashing on phones

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I’m working on a NextJS project, whenever I use it on my computer it works flawlessly. But when trying to access pages on my phone, I get the following error.[image: The error message]

It’s weird because my app doesn’t use anything remotely related to ethereum.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are you doing differently on mobile devices? Do you render any components only on mobile screens (or on smaller screens)?

Comment: No difference, same exact page on every device

Comment: Do you also encounter this issue, if you use the small size on your desktop? What element exactly is `undefined`. A little bit more information would be helpful ( [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) )

Comment: I found that this issue only occurs when trying to open the page using Brave on my phone. I can't think of a reproducible example I can give you though, sorry...

Comment: Did you debug it? You can debug mobile devices. But without any code or whatsoever, it's hard to help. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that ethereum provider is in place. I'm sure if you opened your app in Metamask mobile browser it would work just fine.

Since you haven't included your code snippet I can't help further in this moment